# Advice on Dev Laptop (Lenovo W530) for Mobile Development

Tags: laptop, virtualization, android, ios, windows-phone

I am ordering a Lenovo W530. It is going to be used mainly for mobile (iOS, Android & Win Phone) and backend development. A lot of VMWare virtual machines of course. But not over 2 concurrent virtual machines running at any given point of time.

I plan to run an installation of Mac on a virtual machine for iOS dev. And of course, Win Phone 8 emulators need Hyper-V. So basically, good use of virtualization.

What I really wanted to know was:

Processor: i7 3840 QM is costing me 200 USD extra over i7 3740 QM. The major difference being 8MB L3 cache versus 6MB L3 cache. You can refer to this link for a detailed comparison - http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Core-i7-3840QM-vs-Intel-Core-i7-3740QM. Do you think it's going to make any significant difference with my main objective, ie: mobile & tablet emulators running on virtual machines? Is it worth spending the extra 200 USD?

Graphic Card: NVIDIA Quadro K2000M is costing me 250 USD extra over K1000M but giving me double the performance. Do you think it's going to make any difference with my main objective, ie: mobile & tablet emulators running on virtual machines? Is it worth spending the extra 250 USD?

Many thanks in advance.